# Loading an ImageIcon onto an existing JLabel

Tags: java, jlabel, imageicon

I already know that a `JLabel` can use an `ImageIcon` in the declaration of the `JLabel`, like this.

```
JLabel stick = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("stickPicture.gif"));
```

My question is, how to assign the picture to the `JLabel` after declaration.  For example (this isn't actually the code that works, this is just the technique that I thought might have worked)

```
JLabel stick = new JLabel();
stick = new ImageIcon("stickPicture.gif"));
```

Kind of an odd question, just wondering if it can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JLabel#setIcon(Icon).

```
JLabel stick = new JLabel();
stick.setIcon(new ImageIcon("stickPicture.gif"));
```

Comment: What if stick was an element in an array, why would this not work>

 JLabel stick[] = new JLabel[10]; 
 stick[5].setIcon(new ImageIcon("stick.gif"));

I get a null pointer error when doing this^.  Do you know why?

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException because stick[5] is not defined.  Otherwise, that piece of code works fine.

Comment: The declaration code for the array is right after the "public class Window{"  and where I assign stick[5] to imageIcon stick.gif is in the contructor for the class.  And I still get a null pointer exception, do you know what might have caused this?